# web service, how to convert and place the Microsoft CA certificate in the signature part of SoapUI

Tags: java, web, service, soapui

very new with the web services and integrations so please ignore if i am not very understandable.

Environment:
1- CA server(Microsoft) generate certificate for clients
2- Clients install the certificate in their operating system.
3- clients connect the web service, with user,password and signature(while web service allow the user to login with our signature its file but when they restrict to login with signature it cant because i have to find and place in signature part).

now i have received CA and installed in my system but when i want to authenticate user i cant because i have not set the signature.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://integration.gwclient.smallsystems.cma.se/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <int:logon>
         <username>?</username>
         <password>?</password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <signature>?</signature>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <clientWSUrl>?</clientWSUrl>
      </int:logon>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Question:
i am working with java, any hint or support to convert the .pfx certificate file and place it in signature so i get login and create the session.
or any conversion that can create the signature from ca certificate.

thanks in advance

Comment: There is no need to convert .pfx file, since Java supports that file format as a keystore type. So it seems you are asking how to generate a signature of *?something?*. Have you done *any* research into how to generate signatures using Java?

Comment: So, looks like the server expects a pfx cert. Very likely that you need to convert pfx cert to base64. In java program, set the java field that maps to <signature> to the base64 string

Comment: Yes self signature by java, but here I have certificate installed in my system, how I can use it in soapui as it requires signature. I believe there must be separate software to generate signature from that ca

Comment: @DonHa can you post me any support links

Comment: Sorry I can't find any specific link for this, just speaking from my experience of working with java and web service.

Comment: If you use SoapUI, there is a option to insert cert as Base64, try it.